# Linux Auditd: Error receiving audit netlink packet (No buffer space available)

Tags: linux, audit, auditd, buffer

I have some Linux servers that are getting errors like the below in the logs...

```
auditd[1074]: Error receiving audit netlink packet (No buffer space available)
```

I know HOW to resolve the issue (tweak the audit buffer setting in audit.rules), but I'm wondering WHAT is the impact of this?

Am I actually losing auditd events in the blog?  Is it failing to write the events when it runs out of buffer space?

I have been Googling, but I haven't found a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try increasing auditd's buffer size. In rhel 8 is would be in/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules

Comment: In the end, this is what I wound up doing.  I've been tuning this on a per-server basis.